# How to launch container with user namespace configuration?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, linux-namespaces

In the below docker file, base image(`jenkins/jenkins`) is providing a user `jenkins` with UID `1000` and GID `1000`, within container.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

# Install some base packages

# Use non-privileged user provided by base image
USER jenkins # with uid 1000 and GID 1000

# Copy plugins and other stuff
```

---

On the docker host(EC2 instance), we also have similar UID & GID created,

```
 $ groupadd -g 1000 jenkins
 $ useradd -u 1000 -g jenkins jenkins
 $ mkdir -p /abc/home_folder_for_jenkins
 $ chown -R jenkins:jenkins /abc/home_folder_for_jenkins
```

to make sure, container can write files to `/abc/home_folder_for_jenkins` in EC2 instance.

---

Another aspect that we need to take care in same EC2 instance, is to run containers(other than above container) to run in non-privileged mode.

So, below configuration is performed on docker host(EC2):

```
$ echo dockremap:165536:65536 > /etc/subuid
$ echo dockremap:165536:65536 > /etc/subgid
$ echo '{"debug":true, "userns-remap":"default"}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

---

This dockremap configuration is not allowing jenkins to start and docker container goes in `Exited` state:

```
$ ls -l /abc/home_folder_for_jenkins
total 0
```

After removing docker remap configuration, everything work fine.

---

Why  dockremap configuration not allow the jenkins container to run as `jenkins` user?

Comment: Since NS are used, UID 1000 on the host is not the same as UID 1000 in your running container. Try opening a shell in your container using `docker run` or `docker exec` and run your `chown` command from inside the container. You may then check ownership again from the host system and you'll see that owner is not 1000.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually fighting with this because it seems not very portable but this is the best I found. As said above on your docker host the UID/GID are the ones from the container + the value in `/etc/subuid` & `/etc/subgid`.
So your "container root" is 165536 on your host and your user jenkins is 166536 (165536 + 1000).

To come back to your example what you need to do is

```
$ mkdir -p /abc/home_folder_for_jenkins
$ chown -R 166536:166536 /abc/home_folder_for_jenkins
```

Comment: Nope its not working... jenkins container is not able to write in `/abc/home_folder_for_jenkins`

Comment: What is the owner of the Jenkins process **from the host** ? (something like `ps aux | grep -i jenkins`)

Comment: Jenkins container is going in an `Exited` state in seconds. So, I could not `ps aux`. Once I remove user namespace configuration, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

User namespaces offset the UID/GID of the user inside the container, and any files inside the container. There is no mapping from the UID/GID inside the container to the external host UID/GID (that would defeat the purpose). Therefore, you would need the offset the UID/GID of the directory being created, or just use a named volume and let docker handle this for you. I believe that UID/GID on the host would be 166536 (165536 + 1000) (I may have an off by one in there, so try opening the directory permissions if this still fails and see what gets created).

Comment: Let me try 165536+1000 in both subuid and subgid

Comment: I modified `/etc/subuid` & `/etc/subgid` file to 166536:65536 but no luck